# Sphinx: How can I put code block in a specific variable description in autodoc?

Tags: python-sphinx, autodoc

I want to put few lines of code sample in description of a parameter. It's possible  to add :param, the :type, etc. But is it possible to add a block of comments in front of the :param? 
Here's the code that I'm using now:

```
    :param namespace_type: defines the category of the equation.
    :type namespace_type: str
    :param n_comp: number of compartments in the neuron
    :type n_comp: int
    :param layer_idx: indices of the layers in which neuron resides.
    :type layer_idx: array
    :param eq_template_soma: the template equation used for soma in brian2:
    dgeX/dt = -geX/tau_eX : siemens
    dgealphaX/dt = (geX-gealphaX)/tau_eX : siemens
    dgi/dt = -gi/tau_i : siemens
    dgialpha/dt = (gi-gialpha)/tau_i : siemens
```

which produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1J43.jpg) and as you can see the equation part (which is in the format that is used in brian2 module) is shown as unaligned plain text. I want to put those equations as a code sample.

Comment: What on earth is wrong with this question that I get -1 ?!

Comment: Maybe the downvoter (not me) thought that you should show what you have tried.

Comment: @mzjn I fixed it. Is it ok now?

Comment: Have you tried to use a standard reST literal block? http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#literal-blocks

Comment: Document all parameters together (nothing in between them) and put code examples at the end of the docstring. That's what I can think of.